# call WCF service on iOS when it is using Proxy Object on Client

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, service, client-side

I am developing iphone app to call a WCF web service. I read about the possible ways of calling a web service using iOS but the problem is currently the client app is using proxy object to call service , is it possible to have same Proxy object in iOS or anyway to simulate it ? OR is there any way to find out what is the final URL or Object that is going to be sent to server ?

my shortcut solution is to use Fiddler.exe to monitor http request and see what is sent to server . but by right it should not be the only way ...

Comment: services are already long time working and they are not written by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use fiddler , there are a few options in front of you as below :

1- using NSURLConnection , NSXmlParser and NSHttpRequest to implement a SOAP or REST message. (this way is not recommanded because you need to write down all the SOAP structure.)

2- using using SudzC.com to create a iOS Client side, you can find the tutorial on http://www.sudzc.com

Note : there are a few problems when using SudzC, please use below article to handle the issues : 
http://blog.exadel.com/working-with-ios-and-soap/

Good luck.